# Jquery selector for class n

Tags: jquery

I have a number of div elements that have classes `collapse in` on them. Some of these classes have another class starting `level-n` where n could be any number from 1.

I need a selector that will give me back all div elements with collapse in classes and where they also have a level where the level is greater than 1.

`$(div.collapse.in)` will give me my starter, but how can I extend this to narrow it further by level-n?

Comment: How is your HTML structured? You could do this quite easily if the elements are nested properly, something like `.parent > .child >` to get the first second only. You should do everything possible to avoid having ugly explicit `level` classes.

Comment: @eisbehr - I want all divs that have the classes `collapse` and `in` but they must also have a `level-xx` class where xx is greater than 1. There may be div classes with both 'collapse' and 'in' but they may not have a level class and so should not be part of the selection.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Saw it later. My fault. See my answer ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the div elements are not necessarily in a parent child hierarchy. Hence I just want to select  ALL dives with these classes regardless of where they are on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a selector, which check if the `class` attribute of the element starts with or contains `level-`.

```js
$('div[class*=level-].collapse.in').css("color", "#f00");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse in">.collapse.in</div>
<div class="asd level-1 collapse in">.level-1.collapse.in</div>
<div class="collapse in">.collapse.in</div>
<div class="level-2 collapse in">.level-2.collapse.in</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of attribute selector to filter out div containing level-n classes. See below code

[Attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```js
$(function(){
  $('div.collapse.in[class*=level-]').css("color", "#f0f");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse in">collapse in</div>
    <div class="collapse in level-1">level-2</div>
    <div class="collapse in">collapse in</div>
    <div class="collapse in level-2">level-2</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div.collapse.in').not('div.collapse.level-1')
```

will give you all the elements except the one with the level 1 class.